# Showing multiple metrics with conditions and calculation in visualize tool in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation, kibana-6

I want to create a table in the Visualize tool in Kibana where I show several metrics with condition and calculcation. I have created a generic example in excel, see below. I know the basics. On how to produce the first two columns, be the other ones are harder. I tried looking into adding JSON input with adding another Count and adding a script, but i dont get it to work unfortunately. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Could you edit question and show what you tried to do in Kibana and how?
And where do you struggle?

Comment: I solved the problem by using Visual Builder. It has more complex operations such as Filter Ratios and easily add multiple metrics.